# Initializing dynamic character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm making a function that searches through a sentence to find a letter. Right now, I'm having trouble initializing a dynamic array for the user's sentence.

```
char * get_info(char *ch) {
  char *str;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter a sentence to seach: ");
  while ((str[i++] = getchar()) != '\n');
  str[i] = '\0';
  printf("Enter a character to search for: ");
  *ch = getchar();

return str;
}
```

The problem lies when I call str[i++]. Nothing I've tried or looked has helped so far. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: So, what exactly happened when you called str[i++], and what did you expect to happen instead?  Also, please post the remainder of the program.

Comment: @self. -- no, that is a different, more complicated situation (array *of arrays*).

Comment: You need to allocate memory for your char array.

Comment: Also also: you may be looking for [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Comment: @Zack The principle is the same, there are also dozens of existing questions that solve this. Find one that you think is adequate and mark as duplicate.

Comment: @self. Meh. Better to close as "off topic because inadequate information to debug" IMNSHO.

Comment: Marking as duplicate requires effort...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are dereferencing an uninitialized variable. You need to allocate memory for `str` somehow.

Fortunately for you, there is a function that does this for you, called [`getline()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

```
char * get_info(char *ch) {
  char *str;

  printf("Enter a sentence to seach: ");
  str = NULL;
  getline(&str, NULL, stdin);
  printf("Enter a character to search for: ");
  *ch = getchar();

  return str;
}
```

Comment: ... I should have seen that.  +1 for you.

Comment: How is not guarding against a buffer overrun the fundamental problem when there isn't even a buffer allocated? Filling the input string using getchar() and dynamically using a larger buffer as needed essentially mitigates that problem.

Comment: @jxh I can see that, but that's because it isn't doing memory management **at all**. The OP is asking to dynamically read in the string, so it will need to be expanded at some point once the original buffer's limit is reached. `getline()` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

the declaration `char* str`, can be read as `str` is a variable that will hold a pointer to a character.  No where in your code do you actually allocate this memory for a character (or an array of characters)

If you were to do the following:

```
char *str;
str = malloc(15*sizeof(char));
```

You have not only declared that str will contain a pointer to a character (or an array of characters), but also allocated this memory.

Now while this solves your original question, as jxh points out, this introduces another error.  This code suffers from a classical heap-based buffer overflow, in that if I supply an input line with, say, 30 characters I will use all the memory allocated to the array and over-write other data.

Additionally, you do need to guard against memory allocation failure and attempt to gracefully handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just implement something like this, if your goal is to find a particular letter
within a sentence. It's certainly not perfect but should help you get an idea. Cheers!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    char sentence[30]; //store your sentence

    char letter[3]; //here we store the letter along with the EOL(\0)
    int i;


    puts("Please enter a sentence to search through: ");
    fgets(sentence, 30, stdin); //
    puts("Now enter the letter: ");
    scanf("%2s",letter); //max size for input is 2 including the EOL 


    if(strstr(sentence, letter)){

        printf("The letter '%s' can be found in the sentence.\n",letter);
    }

}
```